# Decimal DateTime formatter in Java or Joda

Tags: java, datetime, formatting, jodatime

I'm writing a file that requires dates to be in decimal format:

> `2007-04-24T13:18:09` becomes `39196.554270833331000`

Does anyone have a time formatter that will do this (Decimal time is what VB/Office, etc. use)?

Basic code goes like follows:

```
final DateTime date = new DateTime(2007, 04, 24, 13, 18, 9, 0, DateTimeZone.UTC);
double decimalTime = (double) date.plusYears(70).plusDays(1).getMillis() / (Days.ONE.toStandardDuration().getMillis())); //=39196.554270833331000.
```

For the example above.

(I started on a DateTimePrinter that would do this, but it's too hard for now (I don't have the joda source linked, so I can't get ideas easily)).

Note: Decimal time is the number of days since 1900 - the . represents partial days.  2.6666666 would be 4pm on January 2, 1900

Comment: er... I was under the impression that decimal time is the number of days since 1900, not 1970: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/214094

Comment: Good catch - that's why the plusYears(70) is there - to "convert" the millis to be from 1900 instead of 1970.  (I just read my code wrong)

Answer (score 1):

You can create a formatter that outputs the decimal fraction of the day. You need to use `DateTimeFormatterBuilder` to build up the pattern manually. The fraction is added using [appendFractionOfDay()](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/api-release/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormatterBuilder.html#appendFractionOfDay%28int,%20int%29).

Comment: Sounds good - I'll give it a crack if/when this MS integration project comes up again... Otherwise, I'll hand out a tick for (plausibly) correct code.

Answer (score 0):

What's wrong with the [getTime()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#getTime()) method?

Comment: The problem is that I need to divide that by 84600, after adding 70 years and 1 day.

Enough stuff there to cause a few edge cases with getMillis()

Comment: Simpler answer: Because it's not what the application on the other end of the xml format is expecting

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately your question is not very clear, but I have a hunch that with decimal time you mean a [Julian date](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Julian_date). There is a post about [converting date to julian date](http://forums.sun.com/thread.jspa?threadID=548884) in Java.

Comment: Not julian date - decimal date: what's used in MS programs.  It's the number of days since 1970

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using the calendar class:

```
final long MILLIS_IN_DAY = 1000L * 60L * 60L * 24L;

final Calendar startOfTime = Calendar.getInstance();
startOfTime.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
startOfTime.clear();
startOfTime.set(1900, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0);

final Calendar myDate = Calendar.getInstance();
myDate.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
myDate.clear();
myDate.set(2007, 3, 24, 13, 18, 9); // 2007-04-24T13:18:09

final long diff = myDate.getTimeInMillis() - startOfTime.getTimeInMillis() + (2 * MILLIS_IN_DAY);
final double decimalTime = (double) diff / (double) MILLS_IN_DAY;
System.out.println(decimalTime); // 39196.55427083333
```

Something to note: This code will only work after 28th February 1900. Excel [incorrectly](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/214326) counts 1900 as a leap year, which it of course is [not](http://science.howstuffworks.com/question50.htm). To circumvent the bug the calculation inserts an extra day (`2 * MILLIS_IN_DAY`), but this of course corrupts any date calculations before the imaginary leap year took place.